# make_date function does not exist in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, datetime, plpgsql

I've got a plpgsql function. I need to take the date 5 days from today, and then divide month into "fives" to takte the start of "last five". The problem is thay make_date does not exist in the posgres version that is used on the server....

```
create or replace function getFirstDayOfFive()
returns timestamp with time zone as $$
declare
    firstDay timestamp;
    startOp timestamp;
begin
startOp = now() - interval '5 day';
SELECT
    make_date(
        date_part('year', startOp)::int,
        date_part('month', startOp)::int,
        greatest(
            floor(date_part('day', startOp) / 5) * 5,
            1
        )::int
    )
INTO firstDay;

RETURN firstDay;
    
end;

$$
language plpgsql;
```

It worked fine last week, but now I got an error when I call it

```
ERROR: BŁĄD:  function make_date(integer, integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 2:     make_date(
            ^
HINT:  There is no function matching provided name and arguments. Maybe you should cast data.
QUERY:  SELECT
    make_date(
        date_part('year', startOp)::int,
        date_part('month', startOp)::int,
        greatest(
            floor(date_part('day', startOp) / 5) * 5,
            1
        )::int
    )
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "getfirstdayoffive" line 7 at wyrażenie SQL


SQL state: 42883
```

What happened that earlier it worked and now it gives error?

[Edit]
I found out that make_date is available from postgresQL 9.4, but on the server there is posthresQL 9.1 is there any way to do the same in this old version od DB? I'm trying to replace the make_date with something like

```
create or replace function getFirstDayOfFive()
returns timestamp with time zone as $$
declare
    firstDay timestamp;
    startOp timestamp;
begin
startOp = now() - interval '5 day';
SELECT
    date to_char(startOp, 'YYYY-MM-')||to_char(greatest(
            floor(date_part('day', startOp) / 5) * 5,
            1
        )::int)
INTO firstDay;
RETURN firstDay;  
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7c05396721c08cf1a5074bb2d175b3a8 Can you try to demonstrate your problem on a fiddle?

Comment: Are you running that on a different server/installation then last week?

Comment: no, I'm running it from the same computer, on the same server as last week. The only thing that changed is I'm on VPN now, because I'm working remotely

Comment: My friend who is in the company run it on our network and gets the same error as I do. We are using pgAdmin 4

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: neither Postgres 9.1 nor 9.4 are [supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  any more - you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: It looks like your logic transforms `now()` into some recent date, but I can't guess what the logic is from your code. You can do that kind of transformation with stuff like `current_date - interval (date_part('day') % 5)  'day'`. If you [edit] your question we'll better be able to give you more precise help.

Comment: I've edited the question, providing some more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simplify this by simply adding the desired number of days to the start of the month. Apparently you only want a `date` so I would also recommend to change the return type to `date`

```
create or replace function getfirstdayoffive()
returns date
as
$$
   select date_trunc('month', current_date - 5)::date 
          + (greatest(floor(extract(day from current_date - 5) / 5) * 5, 1))::int - 1;
$$    
language sql
stable;
```

Comment: Actually I need a varchar, but that's ok :) I will try this, thanks

Comment: @mario: why? You should only convert a date value to a varchar for display purposes and nothing else. But you can always use `to_char()` to convert a `date` to formatted varchar

Comment: because I'm using the result of this function in backend and there the date is as a string (some old project with old structures)